# jQuery css height

Tags: jquery, css

I have no idea why my script is not working...

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

var div_height = $("#content").height();
$(".leftSideBar").css("height", div_height);

var div_height = $("#content").height();
$(".rightSideBar").css("height", div_height);

});
```

As you can see at http://www.willruppelglass.com/ the sideBars don't go all the way down, can anyone tell me why its not? I'm kinda new to jQuery and I am thinking it has something to do with the document ready function, going to read more on this, but if anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.

Comment: don't forget that when you set height as css property you need a measurement. $(".leftSideBar").css("height", div_height + "px");

Comment: Unrelated, but please don't use gigantic images in your site and then use css to make them look smaller. The browser still has to load the large image, it just displays it small. Maybe you just did this as filler for now, I don't know.

Comment: Also, in a wider monitor, your header and footer are not centered, but rather floating to the left. So your hover menus don't line up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your height is off by the height of the images in your `#content` section. Try running the code on `window.load` which fires when all the assets on the page have finished loading:

```
$(window).bind('load', function() {  

    //since your running the same function on the elements,
    //you can select them both at once,
    //which removes the need for a variable that stores the height
    $(".leftSideBar, .rightSideBar").css("height", $("#content").height());

});
```

I noticed that your page is using a webfont; it could be that when `document.ready` fires, the webfont has not yet been rendered and when it does render, it makes the `#content` element taller. Binding to `window.load` should help this if it is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. remove second `var div_height = $("#content").height();`
2. use `outerHeight()` functions instead of `height()`
3. you may need to wait until images load, or specify their height via attribute height

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? Chrome (and maybe all webkit) won't calculate the height of an image correctly if it doesn't have height and width attributes. Try giving your images a width and height attribute and seeing if that works (different approach to Jasper's answer).